# How to get lat long with Precision iOS

Tags: ios, latitude-longitude, mkmapviewdelegate

I want to get the current latitude & longitude with precision (10 digits after decimal point). How can I get that?

Answer (score 4):

That's not possible. Lat/Lon coordinates with 8 decimal places have an accuracy between 1.1132 mm - 0.43496 mm. No mobile-gps is capable to do this.